# Different kinds of C# .NET WinForm applications

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-core

I only occasionly do C# and thus I must have missed some turnoff in .NET technology...

VS (now) offers 2 kinds of WinForm Apps?

[image]

I figured out that the one with **(.NET Framework)** attached is the kind I am used to.
It builds a nice .exe binary in e.g. bin/Debug folder.

I accidentally used the other one 1st and was surprised that it:

1. uses a different platform version .NET 8
2. puts its output in a folder called net8.0-windows
3. seems to be a totally different kind of executable

Especially the startup/runtime behavior seems to be different. There's an additional DLL being created. And there are .json files which are **mandatory** for application start.

Are .NET 8 and (the mainstream) .NET Framework 4.7.2 two **different technologies**/products? Or is the 1st one just the technical evolution of the latter?

Comment: .NET (Core) is originally based on the Compact Framework. Maybe [this comparison](https://stackify.com/net-core-vs-net-framework) could help.

Comment: Yes. .NET 5 and later are actually .NET *Core* versions, a completely different runtime.  .NET Framework is in maintenance mode. All new development goes to .NET Core

Comment: @UweKeim Do you have a source for that? I'm pretty sure .NET Core is not based on any .NET Framework version. Also, the link you've posted has some outdated information (for example, WPF and WinForms _are_ supported since .NET Core 3.0).

Comment: [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/) once commented this several years ago here below some SO question. I trust him very much.